# Custom object records transferring

Tags: community, partner-communities, ownership

I have "Insufficient Privileges" error once would like to change the records owner Under partner portal user. This user is the owner of the record and OWD for this object is Public Read/Write. 
I have this issue for all objects in my org. Looks like records transferring is not available for partner users.

I would appreciate having any inputs on this.

Answer (score 3):

User should have "Manage External Users" permission before changing the ownership in Partner portal.